# Creating image of a two-variable function and finding its optimum in R

Tags: r, function, optimization, graph

I am doing some tasks for my degree and stuck upon a problem of imaging a multivariable function. Following:

```
fb<-function(x) {5*x[1]^2+2*x[1]*x[2]+4*x[2]^2+4*x[1]-2*x[2]-2}
> x<--50:50
> y<--50:50
> z<-outer(x,y,fb)
Error in FUN(X, Y, ...) : unused argument (Y)
```

More than that, I need to find an optimum with maximum on point, but it gives out next when I try without vectors:

```
 optim(c(0,0), fb, control=list(fnscale=-5))
Error in fn(par, ...) : argument "y" is missing, with no default
```

Please advice.

Comment: You should have a 2-D function, e.g., `fb(x,y)` before applying it in `outer`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks as though you have a function of two variables, `x[1]` and `x[2]`, that you are passing into your function as a single vector, `x`. This will cause problems with vectorization of the output. A better way to write it would be

```r
fb <- function(x, y) {
  5 * x^2 + 2*x * y + 4 * y^2 + 4 * x - 2 * y - 2
}
```

This allows you to visualize the function as a surface, for example using `persp`:

```
x <- -50:50
y <- -50:50
z <- outer(x, y, fb)

persp(x, y, z)
```

[image]

To get this working with `optim`, create a wrapper function that puts x and y into a single vector so that it is functionally equivalent to your original function:

```r
result <- optim(c(0, 0), function(x) fb(x[1], x[2]))$par
result
#> [1] -0.4736532  0.3684892
```

To show this is the correct result, we will plot the optimum point on a 2D representation of the surface.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(cbind(expand.grid(x = x, y = y), z = c(z)), aes(x, y, fill = z)) +
  geom_raster() +
  scale_fill_viridis_c() +
  geom_point(x = result[1], y = result[2], color = "white")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `outer`, you should try it with `Vectorize`

```
x <- -50:50
y <- -50:50
z <- outer(x, y, Vectorize(function(a, b) fb(c(a, b))))
```

and for `optiom`

```
> optim(c(0, 0), fb, lower = c(-50, -50), upper = c(50, 50), method = "L-BFGS-B")
$par
[1] -0.4736842  0.3684211

$value
[1] -3.315789

$counts
function gradient
       7        7

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F <= FACTR*EPSMCH"
```